# Python dict.get method apply some function on a key

Tags: python, dictionary

Modified to make it more understandable.

I am testing out the python's dict.get method and need some help on that.

What I am trying to do is that I have a dictionary with some values. I am trying to copy that one value to another dictionary after applying a method on the value of the dictionary. here is how the code looks like

```
test_dict = {"name" : "test-12312", "phone" :"123456"}

result_dict = {}

result_dict['name'] = to_alphanumeric(test_dict.get('name', "Default-123"))
```

What I want to is that if the `name` exists in `test_dict` then apply `to_alphanumeric` function on it and store it in `result_dict` otherwise store the default value. The approach that I am following will also be applied on `Default-123` if the value does not exists which I dont want. I want to apply the `to_alphanumeric` method only when the key `test_dict['name']` exists.

What will be the best way to do that keeping in mind that Default value is in lower case and I only want to convert to upper case if value exists.

Comment: this will also convert the default value to uppercase as well. Which I dont want.

Comment: try to use `defaultdict` or use `setdefault` method on the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not empty, then:

```
result_dict['name'] = test_dict.get('name', '').upper() or 'Default'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
test_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 'default')
test_dict.get('name').capitalize()
```

or

```
test_dict = {}
test_dict.setfdefault('default')
test_dict.get('name').capitalize()
```

Comment: The thing is that it is possible that each key could have tis own different default value depending on the type. For example, name could have `Default` and phone can have `0987654321` for example.

Comment: why don't you implement `to_alphanumeric` function to accept two arguments e.g. `def to_alphanumeric(test_dict, arg_name)` so that you can check inside the function whether a given key exists and based on that return correct value

Comment: I will not like to that since `to_alphanumeric` is also used at many other places and was designed to handle just strings. Doing that will need a lot of refactoring.

Comment: then add another function like `def get_dict_value(test_dict, arg_name)` and pass the return value to `to_alphanumeric` function